# Replace words from list with a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace, text-mining

I have a list of words. Say:

```
list = ['this', 'that', 'and', 'more']
```

I want to replace words in such fashion:

```
x    |y
-----------
this |that
plus |more
```

Every time a word from the list is in column `y`, I want to replace it with what's found in column `x` on the same row. If the word isn't in `y`, it should remain as is. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert this translation table, call it `df`, to a `dict`, then the following will act as the desired replacement function.

```
d = dict(df['y', 'x'].iterrows())

new_list = [d.get(word, word) for word in list]

# new_list: ['this', 'this', 'and', 'plus']
```

Comment: How would I get that dict from my dataframe, given the dataframe has other columns ? So far, all I have managed is a dict that separates the two columns in two sub-dict, as such: {x:{0:this, 1:plus} y:{0:that, 1:more}}

Comment: Also, I believe the result you have has words like x becoming y instead of y becoming x

Answer (score 0):

If you have the translation table in pandas dataframe you can use the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = ['this', 'that', 'and', 'more']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(['x', 'y'], [['this', 'plus'], ['that', 'more']])))

for i,item in enumerate(list1):
    if item in df.y.values:
        repvalue = df.x[df.y == item].values[0]
        list1[i] = repvalue
```

This will overwrite your original list content